# How do I fetch roles that user has? Discord python

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I need to get a list of roles of the user that executes a slash command. I can't seem to find a working solution, that would work with ctx and not with the user.Member or anything else.

My cog code:

```
from discord.commands import slash_command
from discord.ext import commands


class Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Cog connected.")

    @slash_command(guild_ids=[12345], name='test')
    async def test(self, ctx):
        roles = """ here goes some code that fetches roles of the user who executed this command """
        ctx.respond(f"Your roles are {roles}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```

I am using Pycord 2.4.1, but I guess discord.py solutions would also work in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by using `for roles in member.roles`. This declares a variable called "roles" and `member.roles` checks what roles the member has.

Here is the code:

```py
for roles in member.roles:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Roles"
                        description=f"Here are the roles of the following member: {member}"
                        color=discord.Color.red()) # choose any color you would like.
    embed.add_field(name="Roles:", value=roles, inline=False)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Remember to declare a member role:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="roles")
async def roles(interaction:discord.Interaction, member:discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
        member=interaction.user
    for roles in member.roles:
        # rest of the code
```

(Some of this code is based off of [Rexy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77646854/22676652))

PS (just a small note), you can use slash commands by using:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="(command)", description="whatever you want this to be", guild_ids=["whatever guild you want, but ignore this argument if you want it for all guilds"])
```

This will only work if you use these two imports:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import default_permissions
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return the list of roles with the built-in `member.roles` function, then you can create a mentioned list and send it.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="roles")
async def roles(interaction:discord.Interaction,member:discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member=interaction.user
    rolelist = []
    for i in member.roles:
        rolelist.append(i.mention)
    await interaction.response.send_message(' '.join(rolelist),ephemeral=True)
```

### Things to notice:

It is not in cogs

You need `bot.tree.commands` synced for this to work with ctrl+c ctrl+v

It is in discord.py 2.3.2 and python 3.11